# Understanding Peirce's law

Tags: logic

I am trying to understand the meaning of Peirce's Law, namely:
[(P→Q)→P]→P
What does this mean? I am trying to find a practical example of P and Q where the truth of P would follow from the truth of P→Q. Any suggestion?

Comment: Rather, where $P$ follows from $(P \to Q) \to P$.  The informal meaning would be that you can simplify a statement (and disregard  $Q$ altogether), by going from the latter to the former...

Comment: It's easy to establish that in Classical Logic this is a tautology. But there are infinitely many tautologies. So I too have wondered what the importance of Peirce's Law is.

Comment: @Bram28 It seems to be important for historical purposes. According to Wikipedia, Pierce used it as an axiom in his first attempt to formalize propositional logic. It has the look of a first attempt. It is certainly an odd choice for something that is supposed to be "self-evident." I wouldn't give it much thought as anything more than a fun little exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it like this:

If $P$ is false, then $P\to Q$ is true but $P$ is false, so $(P\to Q)\to P$ is false.

Therefore, if $(P\to Q)\to P$ is true, it must be that $P$ is true.

---

You asked for a "real world" example. One issue with this is that we need to treat $\to$ as the material conditional, and uses of "if...then..." in natural language, especially in complicated nested statements, often have a different connotation.

Let's say $P$ is "you get an A in the class" and $Q$ is "you take the final exam". Imagine the syllabus for a class contains the statement "In order to get an A in the class, you must take the final exam". This can be interpreted as $P\to Q$. Now suppose your professor says to you, at the end of the semester, "If I follow the final exam policy in the syllabus, I will give you an A in the class". This can be interpreted as $(P\to Q)\to P$.

What can you conclude? Well, if you weren't going to get an A in the class, then the final exam policy would be trivially satisfied, so the professor would be following the policy, so you'd get an A in the class, contradiction. Thus if what your professor says is true, you must get an A in the class - whether or not you actually took the final exam!

Comment: Or even better: if $(P \to Q) \to P$ is true, it must be false that $P$ is false. Now classically, that implies $P$ is true. But we can't eliminate double negations in e.g. intuitionistic logic. And indeed Peirce's Law fails intuitionistically.

Comment: Thanks for the response, much appreciated. I have no doubt that Peirce's law is correct, but I am (maybe naively) trying to translate it in everyday language. For example if I have P→Q I can take P as "it rains" and Q as "I am taking my umbrella". If it rains, then I am taking my umbrella. Can a similar equivalent be found for (P→Q)→P?

Comment: @Bilou I added an "everyday language" example.

Comment: @Bilou One point to emphasize is that to come up with an example of Pierce's Law, we don't need "the truth of $P$ to follow from the truth of $(P\to Q)$" in order to conclude $P$. We just need that $(P\to Q)\to P$ happens to be true, based on the truth values of $P$ and $Q$. That is, $\to$ is the material conditional here, it doesn't represent any kind of logical entailment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a very simple way of thinking.

True -> True is true, True -> False is False, False -> Anything is True.

Apply it and you can get:

If  is false, then → is true but  is false, so (→)→ is a false statement.

Therefore if (→)→ is true, it must be that  is true.

If P is true and so is Q then we get (→)→ is true. If Q is false then (→)→ is also true (false->anything is true)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from understanding why a formula is true, part of understanding it is why it is useful. Since the other answers explained intuitions for its truth, my answer will be about some of its uses.

One of the important things about Pierce’s Law is that it is enough to yield a semantically complete calculus for Classical Logic from the positive implicational portion of Intuitionistic Logic. Even though it is functionally incomplete, the Implicational Calculus suffices for Classical Logic when $\bot$ is definable, e.g. $0=s(0)$ in $\sf PA$.

Further, the ‘$\Box$’-version of the Grz. axiom of Modal Logic is an instance of Pierce’s law. Namely, where $(P \implies Q):=\Box (P \to Q)$ we have:

$((P \implies \Box P) \implies P) \implies P$.

The standard version of the axiom substitutes $\to$ for the main strict implication. This axiom is important since both the 4 axiom

$\Box P \to \Box \Box P$

and the T axiom

$\Box P \to P$

follow from it. Specifically, the substitution

$(P \land (\Box P \to \Box \Box P))/P$

in the standard Grz. axiom is sufficient to prove both of them.